# Azure data factory scheduled pipe line trigger does not work always

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Azure data factory scheduled pipe line trigger does not work always, its very intermittent, is there a way to troubleshoot and check what was the issue.

Regards
Ravi

[image]

Comment: Can you show your scheduled trigger?

Comment: hi, we need some details about your trigger settings.

Comment: Hi Experts, I have added the screenshot, thanks for looking at this

Comment: Any more details? The screenshot didn't show when it will be triggered.

Comment: trigger is scheduled from 25th of this month at 3.30 AM UTC everyday